# Galilean Transformations Derivation

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I'm trying to understand the Galilean Transformations, as shown in my book. Here's the situation, first and foremost: **Two observers, R (uses Roman Coordinates for its Reference Frame) & G (uses Greek Coordinates for its Reference Frame) are traveling towards each other at a constant velocity $v<<1$. They synchronise their clocks such that the moment that they pass each other is Event O and $\tau =t=0$.** . Here's the book's wordline graph of both observers:

[image]

1. **Now here's what I understand**: Let's look at G's reference frame. IRT G, G is at rest, which is why its worldline is simply a constant $z=0$. On the other hand, IRT G, R is moving at a velocity $v$, but because it's moving at a velocity much slower than $c$, its slope is much less than 1.
2. **Here's what I don't understand**: Let's say we have an Event $E$, which occurs in the coordinates $(\tau, \zeta)$ in G's Reference Frame. Where does it happen for R? And then, *for some reason,* the book draws dotted lines to R's worldline in G, and then another dotted worldline to somewhere seemingly-random on the $\zeta$ axis. I am thoroughly confused. Why is this done? The same thing seems to happen for the Worldlines of R & G in R's Referene Frame, as well. I've circled in Red what confuses me.

I actually understand an alternative derivation of the Galilean Transforms (Image Credit: [The Thinker](http://barisciencelab.tech/TheOriginalRelativist.html)), shown below. But I don't understand the book's derivation.

[image: To be clear]

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Just checking, but you do understand that the dotted lines are drawn parallel to the Roman axes, and the solid lines are drawn parallel to the Greek axes, yes?

Comment: Yes, after all, that's how we get their equations. My question is *why* are they parallel? Perhaps that's more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze the spacetime coordinate from the Greek perspective. The Greek will see that the Roman will approach him/her an meet at origin coordinate.

Then the Greek perform some measurement at event E in the given picture. He/she will realize that the distance at time $\tau$ is $\zeta$.

At that instance, the Roman already passed at time t at z and he/she will see the distance a little further by z - $\zeta$.

Hence the dotted line represent. It should be parallel to get the right measurement of the tilted axes of Roman, as seen from Roman frame of reference coordinate.